# All projects are already under source control

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, git-push

I am trying to push my code to git hub using Xcode source control. when I'm trying to create a repo it says All projects are already under source control. When I commit, it takes the entire library of Xcode including the past projects. When I push, it tells me that the given url is invalid! but it shows the url of another project!! My git account is connected with Xcode. But I've been stuck on this for couple of hours now. And now I dont even see anymore resources available to me that will change anything. All of them are giving me more or less than same info. Can someone help me with it please?! (I know there are other easier options/IDE's but I want to use Xcode source control).
TIA

I have googled it, YouTubed and overflowed it and tried few different ways to do it including creating a repo on git first and then pushing the code to the existing repo, tried to create a new repo from Xcode by source control > create new repo/push/commit. None worked. Watched few tutorials and followed their instructions. and followed the discussions on the given matter from past threads. I re did the entire project from the beginning in different directory by creating a repo on my Mac.